How to reset CSS animation to default state?
I'm currently working on an animation of a countdown ring and I need to find a reliable way of resetting the animation.
Here's the html:
<div class="countdown" id="countdown">
  <svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" stroke-width="12">
    <circle r="40"></circle>
    <circle r="40" id="circle" stroke-dasharray="251.32741228718345" stroke-dashoffset="251.32741228718345px"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>

And here's the css:
svg {
  grid-column : 1;
  grid-row    : 1;
  width       : 105%;
  height      : auto;
  }
[r] {
  fill    : none;
  stroke  : #009c4e;
  opacity : 0.15;
  }
[r] + [r] {
  transform      : rotate(-90deg);
  stroke-linecap : round;
  stroke         : #009c4e;
  opacity        : 0.75;
  animation      : arc 60s linear infinite;
  animation-name : arc, col;
  }
@keyframes arc {
    0% { stroke-dashoffset : 251.32741228718345px; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset : 0px;                  }
  }

I've tried implementing multiple methods from other stackoverflow questions but so far I wasn't able to find anything that worked consistently.
Here's the function I tried but it doesn't work 100% of the time:
function resetAnimationToStart(elementId) {
      var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
      // Remove the animation from the element
      element.style.animation = 'none';
      
      // Force a reflow. Accessing offsetWidth will force a layout calculation by the browser, which is necessary to restart the animation
      element.offsetWidth;
      
      // Use a timeout to ensure the styles have been cleared and the browser acknowledges the removal before starting again
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Reassign the animation to the element to start from the beginning
        element.style.animation = 'arc 60s linear forwards';
      }, 0); // Timeout set to 0ms to allow for the next animation frame
    }

And here's the full code


//functions for calculating the time left
function formatDateToHebrew(date) {
  try {
    // Define Hebrew day names and month names
    const hebrewDays   = ["יום א", "יום ב", "יום ג", "יום ד", "יום ה", "יום ו", "שבת"];
    const hebrewMonths = ["ינו", "פבר", "מרץ", "אפר", "מאי", "יונ", "יול", "אוג", "ספט", "אוק", "נוב", "דצמ"];

    // Get day, month, and year components
    const day   = ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2);
    const month = date.getMonth();
    const year  = date.getFullYear();

    // Format the date in Hebrew
    const hebrewDate = `${hebrewDays[date.getDay()]} ${day}-${hebrewMonths[month]}-${year}`;

    return hebrewDate;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

const zeroPad = (num, places) => String(num).padStart(places, '0');

function getTimeString() {
  try {

    var date = formatDateToHebrew(new Date());

    var timePlus1M = new Date();
    timePlus1M.setMinutes(timePlus1M.getMinutes() + 2);
    timePlus1M = zeroPad(timePlus1M.getHours(), 2) + ":" + zeroPad(timePlus1M.getMinutes(), 2) + ":" + zeroPad(timePlus1M.getSeconds(), 2);

    var timePlus1S = new Date();
    timePlus1S.setSeconds(timePlus1S.getSeconds() + 1);
    timePlus1S = zeroPad(timePlus1S.getHours(), 2) + ":" + zeroPad(timePlus1S.getMinutes(), 2) + ":" + zeroPad(timePlus1S.getSeconds(), 2);

    var timesArray = ["22:45:00", "22:45:00", "22:45:00", "22:45:00", "10:00:00", "12:00:00", "14:00:00", "21:30:00", "23:30:00", "09:00:00", "11:00:00", "13:00:00", "15:00:00", "17:00:00", "19:00:00", "21:00:00", "09:00:00", "11:00:00", "13:00:00", "15:00:00", "17:00:00", "19:00:00", "21:00:00", "09:00:00", "11:00:00", "13:00:00", "15:00:00", "17:00:00", "19:00:00", "21:00:00", "09:00:00", "11:00:00", "13:00:00", "15:00:00", "17:00:00", "19:00:00", "21:00:00", "09:00:00", "11:00:00", "13:00:00", "15:00:00", "17:00:00", "19:00:00", "21:00:00", "10:00:00", "12:00:00", "14:00:00", "22:45:00", "22:45:00", "13:30:00", "21:30:00", "13:30:00", "19:30:00", "13:30:00", "19:30:00", "13:30:00", "19:30:00", "13:30:00", "19:30:00", "13:30:00", "19:30:00", "13:30:00", "13:05:00", "21:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:00:00", "18:00:00", "18:00:00", "18:00:00", "13:05:00"];
    var datesArray = ["שבת 06-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "שבת 06-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ו 05-אפר-2024", "יום ו 05-אפר-2024", "יום ו 05-אפר-2024", "שבת 06-אפר-2024", "שבת 06-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ו 12-אפר-2024", "יום ו 12-אפר-2024", "יום ו 12-אפר-2024", "שבת 06-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ו 05-אפר-2024", "שבת 06-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ו 12-אפר-2024", "יום ו 05-אפר-2024", "שבת 06-אפר-2024", "יום א 07-אפר-2024", "יום ב 08-אפר-2024", "יום ג 09-אפר-2024", "יום ד 10-אפר-2024", "יום ה 11-אפר-2024", "יום ו 12-אפר-2024"];

    for (var i = 0; i < timesArray.length; i++) {
      if (datesArray[i].replace(/\xA0/g, ' ') == date && timesArray[i] <= timePlus1M && timesArray[i] > timePlus1S) {
        return timesArray[i];
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return null;
}

let timeString = getTimeString();

if (timeString == null) {
  timeString = "00:00:00";
  console.log("timeString is null!");
  //document.getElementById("countdown-p").innerHTML = "timeString is null!";
}

var timeComponents = timeString.split(":");
var endTime = new Date();
endTime.setHours(parseInt(timeComponents[0], 10), parseInt(timeComponents[1], 10), parseInt(timeComponents[2],
  10), 0);


var time     = endTime - new Date();
var timeLeft = Math.floor(time / 1000); //var timeLeft = Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
//console.log("time jump",  60 - timeLeft + "seconds");
//jumpToAnimationTime('circle' ,60 - timeLeft)
console.log("time jump", timeLeft + "seconds");

var max = (2 * 60);
if (timeLeft > 0 && timeLeft < max) {
  jumpToAnimationTime('circle', timeLeft)

  var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get the current time
    var now = new Date();

    // Calculate the time remaining in milliseconds
    var distance = endTime - now;

    // Calculate minutes and seconds
    //var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    var seconds = Math.floor(distance / 1000);

    // Ensure single-digit minutes and seconds are preceded by a zero
    var formattedSeconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    console.log("formattedSeconds", formattedSeconds);
    if (formattedSeconds == 61) {
      console.log("resetting animation")
      try {
        // document.getElementById('circle').style.strokeDasharray = '251.32741228718345px';
        resetAnimationToStart('circle')
        console.log(document.getElementById('circle'));
        var shouldPlay = true;
        if (shouldPlay == true) {
          var audio = document.getElementById('1min');
          audio.muted = false;
          audio.play();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    if (formattedSeconds == 0) {
      document.getElementById("countdown-p").innerHTML = "00";
      document.getElementById('circle').style.strokeDasharray = '0px';
      document.getElementById('circle').style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
      clearInterval(x);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("countdown-p").innerHTML = formattedSeconds;
    }

  }, 250);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------
function jumpToAnimationTime(elementClassName, timeInSeconds) {

  var element = document.getElementById(elementClassName);
  console.log(element);
  // Pause the animation
  element.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';

  // Set a negative animation delay to jump to the desired time
  element.style.animationDelay = `0s`;

  // Force a reflow to apply the changes
  element.offsetWidth;

  // Resume the animation
  element.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
}

function resetAnimationToStart(elementId) {
  console.log("resetfunc")
  try {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    // Remove the animation from the element
    element.style.animation = 'none';

    // Force a reflow. Accessing offsetWidth will force a layout calculation by the browser, which is necessary to restart the animation
    void element.offsetWidth;

    // Use a timeout to ensure the styles have been cleared and the browser acknowledges the removal before starting again
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Reassign the animation to the element to start from the beginning
      element.style.animation = 'arc 60s linear forwards';
    }, 0); // Timeout set to 0ms to allow for the next animation frame
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
svg {
  grid-column : 1;
  grid-row    : 1;
  width       : 105%;
  height      : auto;
  width : 400px; 
  }
[r] {
  fill    : none;
  stroke  : #009c4e;
  opacity : 0.15;
  }
[r] + [r] {
  transform      : rotate(-90deg);
  stroke-linecap : round;
  stroke         : #009c4e;
  opacity        : 0.75;
  animation      : arc 60s linear infinite;
  animation-name : arc, col;
  }
@keyframes arc {
    0% { stroke-dashoffset : 251.32741228718345px; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset : 0px;                  }
  }
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="./countdown_chance_60s_BG.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<p id="seconds-text">שניות</p> 

<audio id="1min" preload="auto" muted src="./chance_1min_1c51aee4.wav"></audio>

<p id="countdown-p"></p>

<div class="countdown" id="countdown">
  <svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" stroke-width="12">
    <circle r="40"></circle>
    <circle r="40" id="circle" stroke-dasharray="251.32741228718345" stroke-dashoffset="251.32741228718345px"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>



Any help would be very appreciated.

Could you explain a bit more what 'resetting' means here as when I run your code it appears to start again as I'd expect.

Hi there, To be more specific, the countdown is initiated at about two minutes before the desired time, so I need to be able to reset the countdown ring using a js function at the 60 seconds mark

Are you looking for animation-delay?

I actually tried using animation delay but I didn't find a value which causes a good reset of the animation

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking since the animation works as defined and resets appropriately. If there are additional requirements these should be [edit]ed into the question with appropriate code.

What browser and OS are you using and please show us how you define he element to be reset.

I'm testing on chrome on a windows machine although the actual environment this would be running on is CEF on a windows machine but the issue replicates in both instances with no apparent cause or pattern

I added the entire html with the full logic @A Haworth

your css stroke-dashoffset are SVG property, and there is no unit in SVG. use stroke-dashoffset : 251.32741228718345;
